# How to predict the probability of an empty string using BERT

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Suppose we have a template sentence like this:

- "The ____ house is our meeting place."

and we have a list of adjectives to fill in the blank, e.g.:

- "yellow"
- "large"
- ""

Note that one of these is an empty string.

The goal is to compare the probabilities to select the most likely word to describe "house" given the context of the sentence. If it's more likely to have *nothing*, this should also be taken into consideration.

We can predict the probability of each word filling in the blank, but how would we predict that the likelihood of there being no adjective to describe "house"?

To predict the probability of a word:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM
import torch
from torch.nn import functional as F

# Load BERT tokenizer and pre-trained model
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased', return_dict=True)

targets = ["yellow", "large"]
sentence = "The [MASK] house is our meeting place."

# Using BERT, compute probability over its entire vocabulary, returning logits
input = tokenizer.encode_plus(sentence, return_tensors = "pt") 
mask_index = torch.where(input["input_ids"][0] == tokenizer.mask_token_id)[0] 
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(**input) 

# Run softmax over the logits to get the probabilities
softmax = F.softmax(output.logits[0], dim=-1)

# Find the words' probabilities in this probability distribution
target_probabilities = {t: softmax[mask_index, tokenizer.vocab[t]].numpy()[0] for t in targets}
target_probabilities
```

This outputs a list of the words and their associated probabilities:

```
{'yellow': 0.0061520976, 'large': 0.00071377633}
```

If I try to add an empty string to the list, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-6f726220a108> in <module>
     18 
     19 # Find the words' probabilities in this probability distribution
---> 20 target_probabilities = {t: softmax[mask_index, tokenizer.vocab[t]].numpy()[0] for t in targets}
     21 target_probabilities

<ipython-input-62-6f726220a108> in <dictcomp>(.0)
     18 
     19 # Find the words' probabilities in this probability distribution
---> 20 target_probabilities = {t: softmax[mask_index, tokenizer.vocab[t]].numpy()[0] for t in targets}
     21 target_probabilities

KeyError: ''
```

This is because BERT's vocabulary contains no empty string, so we can't look up the probability of something that doesn't exist in the model.

How should we get the probability of there being no word to fill in the blank? Is this possible with the model? Does it make sense to use the empty token `[PAD]` instead of an empty string? (I've only seen `[PAD]` used at the end of sentences, to make a group of sentences the same length.)

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this problem is to compare the sentence scores by adding the log-softmax of each token.

First, I should say that logits scores in BERT aren't really probabilities when you use softmax on them. But it seems this is an acceptable approach. So, I will use that as well.

Second, you should also consider cases that the adjective has several tokens. My solution also solves issues with multiple tokens.

Here is the code fix:

```
targets = ["", "yellow", "large", "very large"]
target_log_P = {t: None for t in targets}
for target in target_log_P:
     input = tokenizer.encode_plus(sentence.replace("[MASK]", target), return_tensors = "pt")
     output = model(**input)
     target_log_P[target] = sum([
         torch.log(F.softmax(output.logits[0][i], dim=-1)[idx])
         for i, idx in enumerate(input['input_ids'][0])
     ]).item()
```

Maybe there is a pipeline for this and my solution here is not a standard way, but it seems working...

Here are the results:

```
>>> target_log_P
{'': -37.5234375, 'yellow': -37.08171463012695, 'large': -35.85972213745117, 'very large': -46.483154296875}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have one question while I look at this solution a little bit more, do you think it would make better sense to apply a mask for every word in a multi-word target, instead of just one mask?

Comment: I'm trying to find the "probability" of the target word when the model does not see it by searching through the vocabulary for its softmax-normalized logit, but this solution exposes the target word to the model by using it directly in the sentence. I'm not sure if this would work

Comment: The issue is that bert reports token scores in bidirectional setup. Changing one token changes context for all other tokens from left and right. Changing only one mask may work a bit but changing the length of the mask also changes the position of all other words to its right, so it's even more off when you only check scores on the masked part. Anyhow, in this solution you still need to search in a dictionary and assign scores for each entry. But the scores represent the overall consequence of that vocabulary choice.

Comment: I just found this related discussion on huggingface about implimenting `class transformers.FillMaskPipeline`: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/10222